# IN CLAUSE CONTAIN MANY VALUES - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, case

I need your advice.

I have a `CASE` statement in my T-SQL query like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN PLAN_GIVEN IN ( this list contains 1700 values to compare ) THEN 'P1'
    WHEN PLAN_GIVEN IN ( this list contains 1800 values to compare ) THEN 'P2'  
    ELSE NULL
END AS PLAN_NAME
```

I cannot list all 1700 values `IN (  ) THEN 'P1'` as it will not look good with all those values.

I tried saving 1700 values and 1800 values into a `lookup_table` like

```
lookup_table  

columnA = all 1700 values                 
columnB = all 1800 values
```

and used this query:

```
CASE 
    WHEN PLAN_GIVEN IN (SELECT columnA from lookup_table) THEN 'P1'
    WHEN PLAN_GIVEN IN (SELECT columnB from lookup_table) THEN 'P2'  
    ELSE NULL
END AS PLAN_NAME
```

The above code is working but it is taking more time to execute almost 10 minutes to complete the execution.

Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Where are these 1700 values coming from? You could pass them into a table-valued parameter if they're coming from an application. Or you could add a column to the table and update it once - set it to true for any row that matches the criteria. Now, as long as that's maintained, your query can now just say WHERE IsInThisCrazyList = 1.

Comment: Thanks for the response Aaron!! These values are not coming from any application. Our client gave us these values to compare against the query. I cannot change the structure of our existing tables, so i will try to use table-valued parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `PLAN_GIVEN IN`, try using `EXISTS`:

```
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL from lookup_table WHERE PLAN_GIVEN = columnA) 
         THEN 'P1'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL from lookup_table WHERE PLAN_GIVEN = columnB) 
         THEN 'P2'  
ELSE NULL
END AS PLAN_NAME
```

Alternatively, try joining to your lookup table and comparing with the lookup values in your `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT ...
       CASE PLAN_GIVEN
           WHEN lookup_table.columnA THEN 'P1'
           WHEN lookup_table.columnB THEN 'P2'  
           ELSE NULL
       END AS PLAN_NAME
       ...
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN lookup_table 
  ON PLAN_GIVEN IN (lookup_table.columnA, lookup_table.columnB)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Mark!! I used the first method of yours its still taking more time. I am trying your second method. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd change the lookup table into something like this:

```
Value  Name
-----  ----
123    P1
456    P1
...    ...
789    P2
...    ...
```

with the clustered index on `Value`.

After that, you can simply outer-join the lookup table on `LookupTable.Value = otherTable.PLAN_GIVEN` and just pull `LookupTable.Name` in the SELECT clause, i.e. something like this:

```
SELECT
  ...
  lookup.Name AS PLAN_NAME,
  ...
FROM
  ...
  LEFT OUTER JOIN LookupTable lookup ON lookup.Value = otherTable.PLAN_GIVEN
WHERE...
...
```

Please note that I'm assuming the lookup values to be unique, which seemed to me only natural given how you were processing them in your CASE expression.

Answer (score 1):

First use one of the solutions @MarkBannister gave.  Second put indexes on each column of your lookup_table.

```
 CREATE INDEX IX_lookup_table_A ON lookup_table(columnA)
 CREATE INDEX IX_lookup_table_B ON lookup_table(columnB)
```

Even if `lookup_table` is a temporary table it's still worth the time to add the indexes.  And if it's a static table then its WELL worth the time.

Answer (score 0):

Worth a try

```
select 'P1' 
from table 
where PLAN_GIVEN IN ( this list contains 1700 values to compare ) 
union 
select 'P2' 
from table 
where PLAN_GIVEN IN ( this list contains 1800 values to compare )
```

If PLAN_GIVEN has in index then this could use the index.
I don't think CASE can use an index.

Maybe TVP rather than in